# The following subscribed topics are not assigned to any members

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm still quite new to kafka, and something happened to me which I don't understand. I have 2 apps. One is using SpringKafkas listeners to consumer binary avro messages and process them. For some debugging purposes I wrote trivial second cli app, which take topic, offset brokers etc. to consume it using just plain kafka classes, without spring kafka. Both were working for a while. Recently something went wrong with the server.

Main app now does not consume any messages. During startup is sometimes(!) prints message like: "The following subscribed topics are not assigned to any members ..." When I enable debugging, I see it's spinning on "Leader for partition ... unavailable for fetching offset, wait for metadata refresh".

Ok, I could understand from that, that "something went wrong" with the cluster. What is puzzling me a lot is, that our cli app has no issues whatever to connect to the cluster and prints all messages from beginning of topic. I reverified multiple times, that both apps uses same brokers, same topic, different groupId. Neither app specifies partition id anywhere.

What could be the cause, that one app have no problemm reading from topic, while another is unable to "connect" and consume neither preexisting nor new messages from topic?

Comment: Each version of Kafka do you use ( cluster / API) ? Sometimes, bad things can happen but only for a specific group id, that could explain your issue, but would need more info. Could you share the faulty and healthy application kafka logs when it crashed. Did the faulty application has kind of restart of anything changing its state before the issue occured ?

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'll try to provide some details, but i'm a little bit limited. A)Kafka cluster, which behaves like this, is out of my control, I don't even (yet) don't know zookeeper address, just the brokers. B)I don't know the version, but I'll try to find out, if administrator will respond to me. C) neither app crashed, cli app does have logging enabled. I can enable which ever logging you need. What is it?

Comment: Main app did not crash as well. It just did not "connect". With org.apache.kafka and org.springframework.kafka set to debug, I can see, that it indefinitely spins on  "warn: wait for metadata refresh"

Comment: @MartinMucha Were you able to figure out the problem? I am in same boat now.

Comment: @abb I did not see it in a while, but I don't recall I was able to apply fix of some sort. Maybe I did, I just don't know about it now. Sorry.